# Cannot remove item from cart. Spec is failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec

I have a simple shopping cart app and I am trying to test the following method:

```
  def add(item_id)
    item = Product.find(item_id)
    args = {
      :product_id=>item.id,
      :seller_id=>item.shop_id,
      :price =>item.price
    }
    cart_items<<CartItem.create(args)
  end

  def remove(item_id)
    cart_items.where(:product_id=>item_id).map(&:destroy)
  end
```

The spec for this thing is

```
  it "should remove a product from the cart" do
    cart = Cart.new
    item = Product.create(:price=>3450,:id=>1,:shop_id=>1)
    cart.add(item.id)    
    cart.should_not be_empty

    cart.remove(item.id)
    cart.should be_empty
  end
```

No matter what I do, I cannot get it to pass. The `cart_item.length` is always equal to 1. Not sure why this is happening. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the problem is that you aren't saving the Cart to the database at any point.

Answer (score 0):

I've often found that this is because you aren't reloading from the database after removing the item.

```
cart.reload
cart.should be_empty
```

Comment: Not sure where you are getting the error -- does the backtrace tell you? Where is the find happening?

Comment: I'm using autotest, so no backtrace. :( But the error is coming from the line where the call to reload is occurring.